# Libgdx Dialog Box is Small

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I make a dialog box but it was very small (everything is small (Buttons,texts)) how can I enlarge the dialogue box?

My codes:

```
  Skin uiSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/cloud-form-ui.json"));
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Warning", uiSkin, "dialog") {
                public void result(Object obj) {
                    System.out.println("result "+obj);
                }
            };
            dialog.text("Are you sure you want to yada yada?");
            dialog.button("Yes", true); //sends "true" as the result
            dialog.button("No", false); //sends "false" as the result
            dialog.show(stage);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are handling the Dialog box yourself, you can set its size the same way you set another Actor's size [setSize(float, float)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#setSize-float-float-). If you added the Dialog to Table, then you can call methods from the [Cell class](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Cell.html). I recommend using tables instead of setting the position yourself because you can easily center it, but that's something unrelated to your question.

As for the buttons and text, that is probably because using [Dialog#text(String)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Dialog.html#text-java.lang.String-) uses the skin's default font. Chances are, that font is small and you could be using a bigger font. The easiest way to do this would be to use a [Label](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html). You can also use a [TextButton](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TextButton.html) to change the font on the button.

As for it being small in general, you can always change your Viewport to scale everything in a Stage or make it the same resolution across all devices and screen sizes.